# how to use sunspot_mongo

Tags: ruby, sunspot-solr

In my application i have created a model under mongoDB, then i reindexed it to solr using sunspot_mongo. I want to search from solr, 
My model is,

```
`require 'sunspot_mongo'
 class Post
 include Mongoid::Document
 include Sunspot::Mongo

 field :title
 field :content
 field :author, type: String

 searchable do 
  text :title, :stored => true
  text :content
end
end`
```

and my controller index method is,

```
def index
#@posts = Post.all

search=Post.search do
   fulltext 'hello'
end
@posts = search.results

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @posts }
end
```

end
but it showing error as,
 uninitialized constant Sunspot::Mongo::DataAccessor::BSON

i couldn't fix this error

Comment: whats the version of sunspot_mongo you use?

Answer (score 0):

i used this in gem file

```
gem "sunspot_mongo", :git => "git://github.com/balexand/sunspot_mongo.git", :branch => "fix_rake_sunspot_reindex"
```

your model looks fine

change your controller code as below

```
def index
  search=Post.solr_search do
    fulltext params[:search]
  end
  @posts = search.results

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @posts }
  end
end
```

Comment: use this gem as well

    gem 'sunspot_solr'